# Rails where clause with Geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I have the following issue:

```rb
Person.near([@lat, @lng], 100).includes(:licenses).where(licenses: { state: @state })
```

When I remove the `includes` and `where` statements it returns all near persons, but when I use the `includes` and `where` for some reason it returns nothing

Any ideas?

PD: I already added the `reverse_geocoding` to the model

Comment: you can look at the behavior if you add `.to_sql` at the end of the statement. So, when using `includes` / `where`, it'll make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. You need might need to check if there are persons by given state, that's why your query isn't returning any results.

Comment: @mr_sudaca yes, there are persons with licenses in that state

Comment: maybe you can use `joins` instead and check what's inside of `@state`... might be empty or with a weird value... are you using that inside a controller?

Comment: `includes` and `joins` do different things and have different use-cases. In this case (when using to together with `where`), you should use `joins`. What is `@lat`, `@lng` and `@state`? What does `to_sql` return for both queries (with or without the `where`)?